# What is the percentage of Bachelor or higher degree holder that finish calculus 3?

Tags: mathematics, united-states, reference-request

What is the percentage of Bachelor or higher degree holder that finish multivariable calculus in US?

Please list your reference

Comment: Is "calculus 3" standardised in the US? That is mind boogles to me

Comment: For students that finish three semesters of calculus @Oxinabox

Comment: @Oxinabox: There's a strong tradition in the US of teaching calculus as a three-semester sequence: differential, integral, and multivariable.  It's not standardized in any formal way that I know of, but it's very common.

Comment: Some universities have two semesters of main-stream calculus that include multivariable calculus, while other universities use 3 semesters to cover the same material.  At universities that have 3 semesters of mainstream calculus students are often required to take only 2 semesters for many STEM majors.  Furthermore, there are non mainstream courses (e.g. "calculus for business" or "calculus for life sciences") at many universities.  I think you're interested in how many students complete manistream Calculus III.

Comment: The CBMS survey of undergraduate mathematics programs at http://www.ams.org/profession/data/cbms-survey/cbms2010-Report.pdf has the most recent relevant data that I'm aware of, although I don't think its broken down to the level that you'd like.

Comment: See also the Bressoud report: http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/cspcc/InsightsandRecommendations.pdf This report summarizes a lot of the data from the 2010 CBMS survey.

Comment: @NateEldredge so those 3 calculus units are all the calcuslus someone with a undergrad math major would do? (So no undergrad complex analytics? )

Comment: @Oxinabox: Undergraduate complex analysis courses certainly exist, either required or as electives, but they usually aren't labeled "calculus".

Comment: I would go with around a 1/4 at a large University of 20,000 students. There might be 4 sections of Calc 3 taught each semester with 100 students in each section. So 20%.

Comment: As a side note, I always wondered what was included in the word "calculus" in America. At my (European) undergrad uni we had something called "analysis" that included sequences and series, differentials and integrals, vector (multivariable) analysis, complex analysis and Fourier analysis. This was given over 4 to 5 semesters. Geometry, algebra, linear algebra and topology were separate courses.

Comment: I think that the fact that this question has many comments, a good answer but (currently) net vote of 0 is since it lack motivation. Why do you want to know this? (Yes, "idle curiosity" would be an answer…)

Comment: In the US, mathematics majors typically take calculus (for two or three semesters) along with students majoring in engineering and the physical sciences.  Students in these courses typically don't write any proofs and often aren't asked to read proofs or even apply carefully stated theorems.  Later the mathematics majors will take one or more courses in "analysis" in which the methods taught in their calculus courses are given a more rigorous foundation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Conference Board on the Mathematical Sciences (CBMS) is an umbrella organization representing the main mathematical sciences professional societies in the US.  They've done a series of surveys of undergraduate mathematics programs that include numbers of enrollments in courses at various levels.  The most recent published survey was from 2010.

See 
 http://www.ams.org/profession/data/cbms-survey/cbms2010-Report.pdf

and the summary in chapter 1 of 
  http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/cspcc/InsightsandRecommendations.pdf

Sadly, I don't see specific data on Calculus III enrollments.

However, there are about 300,000 students per year enrolling in mainstream Calculus I in the fall semester.  A smaller number start in the spring or summer.  Many of those students won't make it through Calculus I and II, much less enroll in Calculus III (at many institutions only a few STEM disciplines require Calculus III while other STEM disciplines and non STEM disciplines don't require it), and not all of these students will go on to complete bachelor's degrees.

So I'd be surprised if more than about 100,000 students per year graduated having successfully completed Calculus III.

For comparison, about 1.8 million students per year completed bachelor's degrees in the comparable time frame of 2010-2011.  Thus the percentage is small (likely less than 5%.)

Comment: Do those numbers match your university?

Comment: What about advance placement students. I would think a lot of students pass out of Calc I

Comment: My institution requires Calculus I and II of all students (they're all majoring in science or engineering), but only requires Calculus III of students in some of the majors (many of the engineering and science majors don't require Calculus III.)  Thus we're not representative.  At the University of New Mexico (a more typical big state U with about 25,000 students), there were 123 students in Calculus III this semester.  See  http://www.unm.edu/~rst/Schedule_of_Classes/Spring2016/SCHM/index.html

Comment: See the "Insights" report that I cited above.  A relatively high percentage of students who take AP calculus in high school either don't take the AP exam, fail the AP exam, or end up retaking Calculus I in college.

Comment: So the UNM data match reasonable with your numbers.